# Core data and multiple entites

Tags: ios, core-data

Having a really hard time grasping the way core data works, and I'm hoping I can get some very basic help here.

I have two entities:

```
Profiles<-->>Events
```

I have successfully figured out how to add profiles, view profiles in table view and view events for a profile in a table view via a predicate fetch.

Now, here is where I am lost.  Lets say I want to update an event in the Event entity.  Do I have to do a fetch with predicate to create a Profiles object before I update the Event entity?  Or can I just update the Event entity and somehow tell it which Profile it is associated with via the relationship?

Here is where I have hit the log jam:

```
// add new event
    //NSLog(@"Adding New Event");

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Events"];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY profile.profilename=[cd] %@",[self profilename]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    self.events = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    //insert event info
    NSManagedObject *eventInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


/////////  THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP



}


// save the context
NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
    NSLog(@"Error! %@",error);
}
```

I'm about ready just to create a flat file and work with that!  It's driving me nuts!

EDIT - CHANGED CODE BELOW *******************************************

```
// add new event
    //NSLog(@"Adding New Event");

    Events *newEvent = (Events *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    newEvent.eventdesc=self.eventDescTextField.text;


    NSString *wkst = eventDescTextField.text;
    NSNumber  *wk = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [wkst integerValue]];
    newEvent.weeksout = wk;
```

So now I know I need to tell the Event entity to use the current profile..how do I access the relationship?

Comment: are you wanting to add an event for a specific profile?

Comment: You say your question is about updating events. From which I assume that it already exists. In which case, it already has the profiles relationship set up from when you created the event, so there is nothing for you to do to associate an event with a profile.

Comment: I figured out how to save changes to an existing entry, but adding a new entry is where I'm stumbling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you've provided, I think you have a misconception about Core Data.

It looks like you are trying to get all the events related to a profile. You don't need to create ond perform a fetch request for this. Core Data is an object graph. Which means that if you have an object in an a managed object context, you get its related objects via it's relationships, you don't need to run a fetch request.

Comment: Thanks, yes...that is exactly what I'm having a problem with.  I can't seem to get my head out of SQL and into core data.

Comment: You should be able (depending on how you've created your model) to just write `newEvent.profile = <whatever profile you want to add as the related profile>;`